# difficult "case when" and datediff sql query

Tags: case, datediff

I am trying to make this query work:

```
(case 
when R.DateofRepairInvoice is not null and [Last Repairs Rcvd] is null 
        then isnull(convert(varchar,(DATEDIFF((Case when Format(R.DateofRepairInvoice, 'dd') <= '24' 
                then EOMONTH ( R.DateofRepairInvoice ,0 ) 
                else DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(M,1,R.DateofRepairInvoice))
                    ,MONTH(DATEADD(M,1,R.DateofRepairInvoice)
                    ,15))), getdate())),103),'') end) as [Repair Cash Days]
```

Basically when the condition is met, then calculate the date difference between a case when query and today's date.
I just keep getting red squiggly lines:

[image: Screenshot]

No matter where I add or remove brackets and/or commas there seems to be something missing. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to correct this query, please?

Comment: brackets look inconsistent - is this MSSQL or PostrgreSQL?

Comment: It's MSSQL - I've tried all sorts of ways with the brackets but can't crack it yet.

Comment: I got no help here. I'll close this query.

Comment: try `

CASE 
    WHEN R.DateofRepairInvoice IS NOT NULL AND [Last Repairs Rcvd] IS NULL THEN
        DATEDIFF(DAY, 
            CASE 
                WHEN DAY(R.DateofRepairInvoice) <= 24 THEN EOMONTH(R.DateofRepairInvoice, 0) 
                ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, R.DateofRepairInvoice)), MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, R.DateofRepairInvoice)), 15) 
            END,
            GETDATE()
        )
    ELSE NULL
END AS [Repair Cash Days]
`